# How to configure RoleHierarchy with @Secured annotation using spring's new configuration API?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

Previously this setup was enough to use `@Secured` annotation with `RoleHierarchy`. But this is now deprecated.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    private final RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy;
    private final RoleVoter roleVoter;
    private final AuthenticatedVoter authenticatedVoter;
    private final Jsr250Voter jsr250Voter;

    @Override
    protected AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager() {
        var expressionHandler = (DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler) getExpressionHandler();
        expressionHandler.setRoleHierarchy(roleHierarchy);

        var expressionAdvice = new ExpressionBasedPreInvocationAdvice();
        expressionAdvice.setExpressionHandler(expressionHandler);

        return new AffirmativeBased(List.of(
                roleVoter,
                new PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter(expressionAdvice),
                authenticatedVoter,
                jsr250Voter
        ));
    }
}
```

[The documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/method-security.html) said this is the new way. But with this configuration. `RoleHierarchy` not working with `@Secured` annotation.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    static MethodSecurityExpressionHandler methodSecurityExpressionHandler(RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy) {
        DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler handler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        handler.setRoleHierarchy(roleHierarchy);
        return handler;
    }
}
```

Wham I missing here?

Comment: Show your `roleHierarchy` bean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a advisor bean directly as below

```
    @Bean
    @Role(BeanDefinition.ROLE_INFRASTRUCTURE)
    static AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor securedAuthorizationAdvisor() {
        SecuredAuthorizationManager manager = new SecuredAuthorizationManager();
        AuthoritiesAuthorizationManager authoritiesAuthorizationManager = new AuthoritiesAuthorizationManager();
        authoritiesAuthorizationManager.setRoleHierarchy(authorities -> null);//set your RoleHierarchy
        manager.setAuthoritiesAuthorizationManager(authoritiesAuthorizationManager);
        return AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor.secured(manager);
    }
```

[The official doc note](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/architecture.html#authz-hierarchical-roles):

RoleHierarchy bean configuration is not yet ported over to `@EnableMethodSecurity`. As such this example is using AccessDecisionVoter. If you need RoleHierarchy support for method security, please continue using `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` until [gh-12783](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/12783)  is complete. At present, I see that [PR-14260](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/pull/14260) has been merged into the 6.3.0-M1 milestone.

Comment: The official Q&A makes it very clear
Note:
RoleHierarchy bean configuration is not yet ported over to EnableMethodSecurity. As such this example is using AccessDecisionVoter. If you need RoleHierarchy support for method security, please continue using @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity until github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/12783 is complete.
At present, I see that PR14260 has been merged into the 6.3.0-M1 milestone.

Comment: @DingHao Thank you. Maybe you should add your comment to your answer with a link to the doc and to the issue for furture users, which are already using 6.3.

Comment: Since the old configuration is still working, I decided to wait for the next spring's releases.